# How to add custom notes based on checkout option?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add a custom note automatically per order, based on if certain payment options are selected at checkout.

This would be a new line below the customers order notes.

Answer (score 0):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php to achieve the above -

```
function modify_woocommerce_checkout_posted_data_comments( $posted_data ){
    // Add extra custom notes for COD payment
    if( isset( $posted_data['order_comments'] )  && isset( $posted_data['payment_method'] ) && $posted_data['payment_method'] == 'cod' ) {
        $extra_note = __('Your custom notes goes here for COD payments.', 'textdomain' );
        $posted_data['order_comments'] = nl2br( $posted_data['order_comments'] . "\n". $extra_note );
    }
    return $posted_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 'modify_woocommerce_checkout_posted_data_comments', 99 );
```

Here I added extra notes based on `Cash on Delivery` payment method. Change this as per your requirements.

Comment: Awesome, that worked!

By the way the new line shows up as <br />, is there a way to change that?

Comment: For that you can remove `nl2br()` in above